# How to develop and test Svelte components

Tags: es6-modules, svelte

Svelte 3 [FAQ](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-do-testing-svelte-apps) states that testing Svelte (components) isn't really thought out, yet - that there's no template or workflow to follow.

I found EmilTholin's [svelte-spinner](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-spinner) to be the best such, and gave it a try. However, in the `example` side, it pulls in the `Spinner` component from npm, instead of using the component under development.

My take is here: https://github.com/akauppi/svelte-spinner

I've tried to set it up for:
- testability
- fast change-to-demo cycle (no `npm` publishing involved)

<strike>Would someone with Svelte or module experience care to help?  The remaining piece is that my `Spinner` component isn't found by the application.</strike>

Also other comments on the design / choices are welcome.  Maybe we can get a pattern that works well for development, demoing, testing and publishing of components, using Svelte 3.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the acute problem - just reading the warnings and maybe update of `npm` dependencies helped.

Anyhow, since there are no established ways of testing/developing Svelte-made components, I'm leaving this entry visible in the hope that someone would share insights as to good practices on using Svelte.